# Quiz creation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-frontend, lms

I try to create one quiz page I'm passing data from the database I have attached the sample data also the key is similar in all the 3 databases the show element and hide elements are not working as expected but the start timer and displaying first question are doing correctly and I have basic CSS only. Kindly focus only on js to display only one question at a time
what i want is
1)when the page loaded it have to get the first element of b
2)and get the time value of c and start the timer if timer ends it have to get the next element of b and start the timer
3)in d we are having the key and value when the page loaded it have to display the question it have to show only one question at a time that is only one value at a time

The sample data from data base

```
d={'BOT SEC A': [[1, '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '11', '1'], [2, '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']], 'BOT SEC B': [[3, '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3'], [4, '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4']], 'CHE SEC A': [[13, '13', '13', '13', '13', '13', '13', '13', '13', '13'], [14, '14', '14', '14', '14', '14', '14', '14', '14', '14']], 'CHE SEC B': [[15, '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15'], [16, '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16']], 'PHY SEC A': [[9, '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9'], [10, '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10']], 'PHY SEC B': [[11, '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11'], [12, '12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '12']], 'ZOO SEC A': [[5, '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'], [6, '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6']], 'ZOO SEC B': [[7, '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7'], [8, '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8']]}//question_with_section 

        questions_with_sections = {}

        for section_name, question_ids in questionpaper.items():
            section_questions = []
            for question_id in question_ids:
                try:
                    question = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
                    question_data = [
                        question.id,
                        question.question_name,  # Use the actual field containing the question text
                        question.option_1,
                        question.option_2,
                        question.option_3,
                        question.option_4,
                        question.option_5,
                        question.option_6,
                        question.option_7,
                        question.option_8,
                    ]
                    section_questions.append(question_data)
                except Question.DoesNotExist:
                    #print(f"Question with ID {question_id} not found.")
                    section_questions.append({'question_text': 'Question not found'})

            questions_with_sections[section_name] = section_questions

b=['CHE SEC B', 'CHE SEC A', 'PHY SEC A', 'PHY SEC B', 'ZOO SEC B', 'ZOO SEC A', 'BOT SEC B', 'BOT SEC A']//subject names 
c={'BOT SEC A': 61, 'BOT SEC B': 61, 'ZOO SEC A': 61, 'ZOO SEC B': 61, 'PHY SEC A': 61, 'PHY SEC B': 61, 'CHE SEC A': 61, 'CHE SEC B': 61}  // time for each sections to attend
```

The code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      transition: background-color 1s;
    }
    
    #div1,
    #div2,
    #div3,
    #div4,
    #questionDiv {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .numberBox {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #questionDiv button {
      margin: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>


  <div id="div1">
    <!-- Append keys from B dynamically using JavaScript -->
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <!-- Content will be dynamically populated by JavaScript -->
    <button onclick="sectionend()">SECTIONSUBMIT</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <!-- Timer will be displayed here -->
    <h1 id="timerDisplay">Time Remaining: 0 seconds</h1>
    <button onclick="sectionend()">SECTIONSUBMIT</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div4">
    <button id="markForReview" onclick="markForReview()">Mark for Review</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="saveAndNext()">Save & Next</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="clearResponse()">Clear Response</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="questionDiv1">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'submit_exam' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="examname" value="{{ exam }}">
      <div id="questionDiv"></div>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Question will be dynamically populated by JavaScript -->
  </div>


  <script>
    // Sample data
    const D = {
      {
        questions_with_sections | safe
      }
    };
    const B = {
      {
        ordered_sections | safe
      }
    };
    const C = {
      {
        timing_data_dict | safe
      }
    };


    let currentKeyIndex = 0;
    let timerSeconds = parseInt(C[B[currentKeyIndex]]);
    const selectedOptions = {};


    function populateDiv1() {
      const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
      B.forEach(key => {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.textContent = key;
        button.addEventListener('click', () => showKeyValues(key));
        div1.appendChild(button);
      });
    }


    function showKeyValues(key) {
      if (key === B[currentKeyIndex]) {
        const div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
        div2.innerHTML = '';
        const value = D[key];
        if (value) {
          for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            const numberBox = document.createElement('div');
            numberBox.className = `numberBox ${key}-${i}`;
            numberBox.textContent = i + 1;
            numberBox.addEventListener('click', () => takeDivKey(key, i + 1));
            div2.appendChild(numberBox);
          }
        }
        startTimer();
      }
    }


    function startTimer() {
      const timerDisplay = document.getElementById('timerDisplay');


      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        timerSeconds--;


        if (timerSeconds <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          switchKey();
        } else {
          timerDisplay.textContent = `Time Remaining: ${timerSeconds} seconds`;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }



    function switchKey() {
      if (currentKeyIndex < B.length - 1) {
        currentKeyIndex++;
        timerSeconds = parseInt(C[B[currentKeyIndex]]);
        showKeyValues(B[currentKeyIndex]);
        takeDivKey(B[currentKeyIndex], 1);
        startTimer();
      } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }

    function takeDivKey(key, value) {
      const questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');
      const totalQuestionsForCurrentKey = D[key].length;
      hideElements(questionDiv);
      createFunction(key, value);
    }

    // Function to hide elements
    function hideElements(questionDiv) {
      //alert("hide called")
      const radioContainer = questionDiv.querySelector('.radio-container');
      const previousParagraph = questionDiv.querySelector('.question-text');
      //alert(radioContainer)
      //alert(previousParagraph)
      // Check if the elements exist before attempting to hide them
      if (radioContainer) {
        radioContainer.style.display = 'none';
        //alert("radio hidden")
      }
      if (previousParagraph) {
        previousParagraph.style.display = 'none';
        //alert("paragraph hidden")
      }
    }
    // Function to create new elements
    function createFunction(key, value) {
      const questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');
      const questionArray = D[key][value - 1];
      const questionText = questionArray[1];
      const options = questionArray.slice(2);
      // Show the current question
      const questionTextElement = document.createElement('text'); // Change from 'p' to 'div'
      questionTextElement.className = 'question-text';
      // Create a container for radio buttons
      const newRadioContainer = document.createElement('div');
      newRadioContainer.className = 'radio-container';
      options.forEach(option => {
        const label = document.createElement('label');
        const radio = document.createElement('input');
        radio.type = 'radio';
        radio.name = `question${questionArray[0]}`;
        radio.value = option;
        label.appendChild(radio);
        // Create a span for each option text
        const optionTextContainer = document.createElement('span');
        optionTextContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(option));
        label.appendChild(optionTextContainer);
        newRadioContainer.appendChild(label);
        // Check if the current option is the selected one
        if (selectedOptions[key] === option) {
          radio.checked = true;
        }
        radio.addEventListener('change', () => {
          selectedOptions[key] = option;
          handleRadioButtonChange();
        });
      });
      // Append the new container to the questionDiv
      questionDiv.appendChild(questionTextElement);
      questionTextElement.appendChild(newRadioContainer);
    }


    // Function to show elements
    function showElements(questionDiv) {
      const radioContainer = questionDiv.querySelector('.radio-container');
      const previousParagraph = questionDiv.querySelector('.question-text');

      // Check if the elements exist before attempting to display them
      if (radioContainer) {
        radioContainer.style.display = 'block';
      }
      if (previousParagraph) {
        previousParagraph.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }



    function markForReview() {
      const currentKey = B[currentKeyIndex];
      const questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');
      const selectedRadioButton = questionDiv.querySelector('input[name^="question"]:checked');
      const numberBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('numberBox');


      if (selectedRadioButton) {
        const questionIndex = parseInt(selectedRadioButton.name.replace('question', ''), 10) - 1;
        const currentNumberBox = numberBoxes[questionIndex];
        currentNumberBox.style.backgroundColor = 'violet';
        currentNumberBox.innerHTML = '✔';
        switchToNextQuestion();
      } else {
        const currentNumberBox = numberBoxes[currentKeyIndex];
        currentNumberBox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        switchToNextQuestion();
      }
    }


    function saveAndNext() {
      switchToNextQuestion();
    }


    function clearMarkedForReview() {
      const currentKey = B[currentKeyIndex];
      const questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');
      const selectedRadioButton = questionDiv.querySelector('input[name^="question"]:checked');


      if (selectedRadioButton) {
        const questionIndex = parseInt(selectedRadioButton.name.replace('question', ''), 10) - 1;
        const numberBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('numberBox');


        const currentNumberBox = numberBoxes[questionIndex];
        currentNumberBox.style.backgroundColor = '';
        currentNumberBox.innerHTML = '';
      }
    }


    function switchToNextQuestion() {
      const currentKey = B[currentKeyIndex];
      const questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');
      const selectedRadioButton = questionDiv.querySelector('input[name^="question"]');


      const questionIndex = parseInt(selectedRadioButton.name.replace('question', ''), 10);
      // const currentQuestionID = D[currentKey][questionIndex];
      alert(questionIndex)
      let nextQuestionIndex = -1;


      for (let i = 0; i < D[currentKey].length; i++) {
        if (D[currentKey][i][0] === questionIndex) {
          nextQuestionIndex = (i + 1);
          alert(nextQuestionIndex)
          alert(D[currentKey].length)
          break;
        }
      }


      if ((nextQuestionIndex !== -1) && (nextQuestionIndex < D[currentKey].length)) {
        takeDivKey(currentKey, (nextQuestionIndex + 1));
        handleRadioButtonChange();
      } else {
        handleRadioButtonChange(selectedRadioButton);
        alert("Wait for the timer to end or move to the next key");
        handleRadioButtonChange();
      }
    }


    function sectionend() {
      switchKey();
    }


    function clearResponse() {
      const questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');
      const selectedRadioButton = questionDiv.querySelector('input[name^="question"]:checked');


      if (selectedRadioButton) {
        selectedRadioButton.checked = false;
        clearMarkedForReview();
        handleRadioButtonChange(selectedRadioButton);
      }
    }


    function submit() {
      alert("Submitted");
    }


    function sectionSubmit() {
      switchKey();
    }


    function handleRadioButtonChange() {
      const currentKey = B[currentKeyIndex];
      const questionDiv = document.getElementById('questionDiv');
      const numberBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('numberBox');


      const checkedRadioButton = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');


      if (checkedRadioButton) {
        const questionIndex = parseInt(checkedRadioButton.name.replace('question', ''), 10);
        let nextQuestionIndex = -1;


        for (let i = 0; i < D[currentKey].length; i++) {
          if (D[currentKey][i][0] === questionIndex) {
            nextQuestionIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        }


        if (nextQuestionIndex !== -1) {
          const currentNumberBox = numberBoxes[nextQuestionIndex];


          if (currentNumberBox) {
            currentNumberBox.style.backgroundColor = 'green';


            const selectedOption = checkedRadioButton.value;
            //alert(selectedOption);
            selectedOptions[currentKey] = selectedOption;
          }
        }
      } else {
        const currentNumberBox = numberBoxes[currentKeyIndex];
        if (currentNumberBox) {
          currentNumberBox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
      }
    }


    populateDiv1();
    showKeyValues(B[0]);
    takeDivKey(B[0], 1);
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: "not working as expected." What's expected and what's it actually doing? Are there any errors in your dev console?

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your sample data: `D` seems to be missing some commas between key/value pairs, and are the values, such as "questioned," supposed to be string? Otherwise those variables need to be defined. . What are `key3`, `key2`, and `key1` for `B`?

Comment: I just simply type the sample data because you have to know how the data are received I expected to display only one question at a time and if it is the last question of that key it have to alert wait for time end or click end section that is second key but it is not hiding the question it is showing all the question

Comment: So should those items in the sample data be strings?

Comment: Right now, when I run your code, I see errors. Please [edit] your question, and the code within, until it demonstrates the issue you want help with (a [mre]). See [ask] for more tips on asking questions.

Comment: How to solve those errors gives a hint or kindly give the correct code

Comment: Check your console and see what the errors are. We don't know your intentions. If you have a question about a specific error, we can help, but you have to ask about that specific error. Again, for example, what is `questioned`, et al. from your sample data? Is it a string? a variable? If it's a variable, what's its value? And repeat for the remainder of the sample data.

Comment: That is question id of that question because I have a model exam in that exam I have only question id question and options are stored as separate model

Comment: Please update it with actual sample values; we don't know your intentions and can't (and shouldn't) have to guess at what's actually in the data. Then how does that sample data get used in the actual code?

Comment: start with wrapping your string values in quotation marks ["value1", "value2"]. once you've done that if it's still not working, update your question with a runnable example and or at the very least the error that was produced.

Comment: The exact data is entered

Comment: Your snippet still contains syntax errors. I'm not familiar with this syntax: `for section_name, question_ids in questionpaper.items():`; is it actually part of hte code or should it be a commetnt?